# How to remove all build files in QtCreator?

Tags: qt-creator

I click the Clean, but the `.pdb`, `.lib`, `.dll`, `.exe` files still exist.

Idk how to use `jom.exe clean`

[image]

Comment: What Creator version, what OS?

Comment: @spinkus Creator4.2.1, windows 10

Answer (score 5):

Clean from the GUI will just run `make clean` in your project directory. To clean everything, you normally want to run `make distclean` in your Qt project directory. To do that you can run that command directly from the command line, or look in *Build Settings >> Clean Steps* and change the make arguments from "clean" to "distclean".